# Could the view to be pushed up when the keyboard occur?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have created some textfields at the bottom that required users to entry. Is there any method that can push up the view automatically when the keyboard occur?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding), a drop-in universal solution for moving text fields out of the way of the keyboard in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

See Apple's [Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7), or [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/1290641) based in [Calculating Area Covered by Keyboard](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/07/calculating-area-covered-by-keyboard/).

Basically you have to mount your view on a UIScrollView and add a bottom content inset with the same height than the keyboard. Then scroll using setContentOffset:animated:. This is a generic solution that you can reuse.

A more simple but non generic way is, if you have enough space at the bottom of your view without editable controls, you just scroll to a fixed position for each edit box.

Comment: Note, you don't have to use a UIScrollView. You can just decrease the y value of your main view's center property, then increase it again when the keyboard hides. A scroll view is nice because it lets your users decide to see other parts of the interface while they keyboard is there, but it adds a little complication.

Comment: However, I am using the UIViewController for my program, could the problem be solved under this environment?

Comment: @morningstar It would be nice if you linked to or provided some code/screenshot about where/how the center property is changed.

Answer (score 1):

use the -contentoffset property of your view.